# download package dependencies

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 with no internet connection.
I want to use Synaptic to install software and packages to it, referring to [this documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Use_the_Synaptic_package_download_script).

The problem is, I do not have synaptic installed on the laptop, so I need to download the Synaptic package and all of its dependencies (deb files) on another PC and then transfer them to the laptop.

I found the deb files [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/synaptic), but I can only download one file at a time. Is there a way that I could download Synaptic and all of its dependencies at once?

Answer (score 1):

Check out "Sushi Huh?" and the "Keryx Project"

http://sushi-huh.sourceforge.net/

"Sushi, huh? is a program that allows downloading all the packages needed to install the programs you want on GNU/Linux without an Internet connection on your own computer."

https://launchpad.net/keryxproject

"Keryx is an offline package management system
Keryx is a portable, cross-platform package manager for APT-based (Ubuntu, Debian) systems. It provides a graphical interface for gathering updates, packages, and dependencies for offline computers. Keryx is free and open source."

Answer (score 0):

```
I found the deb files here,
```

That's not the `synaptic` package. Is the synaptic source code, and the **build** prerequisites.

The `synaptic` package to install is here http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/synaptic